# AJAX call to different domain without JSONP

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cross-browser

Is there any way to retrieve data via ajax from another domain without using JSONP or any other library (a pure JS solution?)

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing), however it's not supported by every browser.

Comment: And you also have _window.name transport_. Some people use this technique for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is not a library, it's a technique. JSONP itself isn't related to or dependent upon jQuery or anything like that, though jQuery does have support that makes it simple. You can easily do this with plain DOM/JavaScript.

The technique is to dynamically insert a script tag into the document, setting the source to your external server.  The external server should send back JSON data wrapped in a function. The function is called when the script is loaded, of course.

So, say you have a function in your main script, `json_parse`.

Insert a tag like

```
<script src='yourserver.example.com/the_data.php?jsonp=json_parse'></script>
```

And let's say that script sends back the data, wrapped in a function call to the function you specify, json_parse in this case.

```
json_parse({"some":"data","blap":420});
```

And there you go, you've accessed JSON data from an XD server. Note since you're loading a script, this only works for GET requests.